# os.system file names with spaces

Tags: python, terminal, operating-system

Here is my python code (I am on Mac osx)

```
os.system("open Applications/Google Chrome")
```

I cannot figure out how to make spaces, or how to make this work.
Can someone tell me how to make terminal understand this?

Comment: `os.system("open 'Applications/Google Chrome'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add quotation marks around the file path, so it can understand that it is one argument:

```py
os.system('open "Applications/Google Chrome"')
```